# Changing a code in CodePen, black to image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

At first, the black screen greets when this page opens. I want to show the picture instantly, but I can't.

```
const srcDir =  'https://www.apple.com/105/media/us/airpods-pro/2019/1299e2f5_9206_4470_b28e_08307a42f19b/anim/sequence/large/02-head-bob-turn/';
const imgSuffix = '.jpg';

console.log('Hello AirPods-Pro!');

var appleAirPodsPro = {
  init() {
    this.initData();
    this.initImages();
    this.handleResize();
    this.bindEvents();
  },

  initData() {
    this.canvas2 = document.getElementById('02-head-bob-turn');
    this.context = this.canvas2.getContext('2d');
    this.MAX_LEN = 132;
    this.imgs = [];
    this.start = 1;
    this.oldStart = -1;
    this.addN = 1;
    this.interval = 20; // 控制刷新率
    this.leftY = 0;
    this.curScrollY = this.getScrollTop();
    this.startPos = this.curScrollY;
    this.lastPos = this.curScrollY;
    this.isStop = false;
  },
```

all code at this link: https://codepen.io/flcwl/pen/LYYevVr
what code do I need to change?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).